# How to set up .net core service that uses a generic repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am building a generic data repository using .netcore 3.0. with EF Core. How can I set up the service where I don't have to provide the actual entity name such as this:

```
services.AddScoped<RepositoryBase<Feature>>();
```

Is there a way to configure options that will all me to do this?

These are mostly CRUD operations.

The Generic repository base

```
namespace CoreAPI1.Data.Services
{

    public class RepositoryBase<TEntity>  where TEntity : class
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

        public RepositoryBase(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            if (_context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll()
        {
            return _dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The services

```
public static void  ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddDbContext<TruckContext>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
    services.AddScoped<IFileService, FileService>();
    services.AddScoped<IImageRepository, ImageRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<RepositoryBase<Feature>>();
    services.AddControllers();
   // services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Truck));
    services.AddMvc(_x=>_x.EnableEndpointRouting = 
     false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

}
```

The calling controller

```
namespace CoreAPI1.Data.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/features")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FeaturesController :ControllerBase
    {
        private RepositoryBase<Data.Entities.Feature> _repository;
        private IMapper _mapper;

        public FeaturesController(RepositoryBase<Data.Entities.Feature> repository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_repository));
            _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Domain.Models.Feature>> GetFeatures()
        {

            var _features = await _repository.GetAllAsync();
            List<Domain.Models.Feature> _returnedFeatures = new List<Domain.Models.Feature>();


            try
            {
                foreach (var f in _features)
                {
                    var _returnedFeature = _mapper.Map<Domain.Models.Feature>(f);
                    _returnedFeatures.Add(_returnedFeature);
                }
                return _returnedFeatures;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can register the type generically, if that's what you're talking about:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

That would then inject `Repository<Foo>` for `IRespository<Foo>`, for example.

Comment: Check the update. They are using the generic class directly and not the abstraction. Should include a quick mention about that.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Unit of Work class that wraps DbContext and creates repository.

Answer (score 0):

Add Service in Program.cs Class

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IVillaRepository, VillaRepository>();
```

Create Variable of Interface in Controller

```
namespace WhiteLaggoon.Web.Controllers
{
    public class VillaController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IVillaRepository villaRepo;
        public VillaController(IVillaRepository villaRepo)
        {
            this.villaRepo = villaRepo;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var villa = villaRepo.GetAll();
            return View(villa);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Villa obj)
        {  
            obj.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            obj.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                villaRepo.Add(obj);
                villaRepo.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Villa");
            }
            return View(obj);
        }

        [HttpGet("villaId")]
        public IActionResult Update(int villaId)
        {
            Villa? obj = villaRepo.GetById(villaId);

            if(obj == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error","Home");
            }

            return View(obj);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult UpdateVilla(Villa obj)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid && obj.Id > 0)
            {
                villaRepo.Update(obj);
                villaRepo.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
         
        public IActionResult Delete(int villaId)
        {
            Villa? obj = villaRepo.GetById(villaId);

            if(obj != null)
            {
                villaRepo.Remove(obj);
                villaRepo.Save();
                TempData["Success"] = "The Villa Has Been Deleted Successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            TempData["Error"] = "Villa Cannot be Deleted";
            return RedirectToAction("Error","Home");
        }

    }
}
```

Interface :
-> here we are implementing the generic interface to our repo interface by passing the model

```
public interface IVillaRepository : IRepository<Villa>
 {
     Villa GetById(int id);
     void Update(Villa villa);
     void Save();
 }
```

Generic interface with generic type T :

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
 {
     IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, string? includeProperties = null);
     void Add(T villa);
     void Remove(T villa);
 }
```

Repository :
-> here we are getting the context from base class

```
namespace WhiteLagoon.Infrastructure.Repository
{
    public class VillaRepository : Repository<Villa>, IVillaRepository
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

        public VillaRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public Villa GetById(int id) => context.Villas.Where(n => n.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(Villa villa)
        {
            context.Update(villa);
        }
    }
}
```

Generic Repository :

```
namespace WhiteLagoon.Application.Common.Interfaces
{
    public interface IVillaRepository : IRepository<Villa>
    {
        Villa GetById(int id);
        void Update(Villa villa);
        void Save();
    }
}
```